# Highcharts Synchronisation not working: point.highlight

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts, vuejs2

I am very new to Highcharts and I am trying to synchronize my highcharts as shown in https://www.highcharts.com/blog/snippets/synchronisation-of-multiple-charts/ , however I am running into an issue with the below part.

In the link, the first part is below.

```
$('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
    var chart,
        point,
        i,
        event;

    for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
        chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
        event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); // Find coordinates within the chart
        point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true); // Get the hovered point

        if (point) {
            point.highlight(e);
        }
    }
});
```

FYI I am using Vue.js in my application.
I was able to see that 'mousemove touchmove touchstart' events got fired according to console.log('fired') statement, but below line always fails.

```
point.highlight(e);
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _point.highlight is not a function
```

Here is my Vue.js code:

```
$(`#vue-multi-charts-${self._uid}`).bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {

    console.log('fired');  // THIS PART WORKS

    let point,
        chartRefs = Object.keys(self.$refs).filter((k) => k.startsWith('highchartComponent-'));

    for (let i = 0; i < chartRefs.length; i++) {
        let chart = self.$refs[chartRefs[i]][0].chart,
            event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent), // Find coordinates within the chart
            point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true); // Get the hovered point

        if (point) {
            point.highlight(e);
        }
    }

});
```

I went on the Highcharts API but I can't find the document for "highlight" method. e.g. https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point there is no highlight method.

I would really appreciate if someone can provide some help.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in [above script](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/snippets/synchronisation-of-multiple-charts/), the author define `highlight` as a custom methods:

```
Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function (event) {
    this.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
    this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip
    this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); // Show the crosshair
};
```